# How do I connect to SQL Server from Windows without using trusted_connection?

Tags: sql-server, r, database

Struggling with this problem. Right now I am building a service app on a windows machine, which I have been using the following line of code to connect to SQL Server

```
dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = paste0('driver={SQL Server};server=', SERVER, ';trusted_connection=true'))
```

It works great, but my issue is that this application I am building will be used on iOS and eventually a Linux container, so I cannot rely on "trusted_connection" going forward. But, the following code fails for me:

```
dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = paste0('driver={SQL Server};server=', SERVER, ';UID=',USER,";PWD=",PWORD))
```

In that line I removed "trusted_connection" and put in my user name and password that I use to log into my windows machine, but I get this error:

`Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 28000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'fhcrc\sgreenle'`.

The user is what I see when I connect to the server through SQL Server Management Studio, and the passwords match, but somehow I still have this error.

Any advice on how to debug or figure this out would be amazing. This has been a thorn in my side for a while and  I cannot solve it for the life of me, and I fear that my project will be dead in the water without a solution.

Comment: You need to use SQL authentication so, create a login in SQL Server, and put those credentials in the app. And you should never type your Windows password into a connection string or application code - the whole point of Windows authentication is that you don't have to do that.

Comment: Agreed, eventually there will be no password in the code and it will be submitted through an input form by the user. Just trying to test with my own credentials first.

Comment: @AaronBertrand has the right of it - the user name "fhcrc\sgreenle" is what shows us you are using Windows authentication. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode

Comment: And the user will submit what credentials? A login and a password you'll need to create in SQL Server. Because they certainly shouldn't be passing Windows credentials in an input form.

Comment: Now I'm more confused. We have many users who access the server, but each has different premissions about what data they can see. They use network wide credentials to access various machines and servers. My goal is to match up my application with those permissions. Wouldn't creating a new login to SQL Server for the users when they login cause a mismatch with those permissions?

Answer (score 1):

When providing username and password in the connection string, you are using SQL Authentication. Your code sample shows that you are trying to use your Active Directory account for SQL Authentication, but this will not work. You need to create a separate SQL Server account using SQL Authentication and enter those credentials instead. Helpful reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode